# PowerShell script to get the ShowInEditForm property for a site column. i do not want to use PnP PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am trying this script to get the ShowInEditForm property of a site column and then set it to False:-

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://****-admin.sharepoint.com/

Get-SPOSite -Identity https://***.sharepoint.com/


$column = Get-SPOField -Identity "CarNumber"
```

but i am getting this error:-

```
Get-SPOField : The term 'Get-SPOField' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
any advice please?
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Get-SPOField` is not a valid cmdlet, you should use the `Get-PnPField` cmdlet to get the fields.

Comment: thanks but PnP is not allowed to be used inside the client environment as it is an open source technology. any alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this PowerShell:

```
#Set Variables
$SiteURL= "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing"
$InternalName = "MyEditor"
 
#Setup Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
   
Try {
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.UserName,$Cred.Password)
 
    #Get the Web
    $Web = $Ctx.Web
    $Ctx.Load($Web)
 
    #Get the Site Column
    $SiteColumn = $Web.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($InternalName)
    $Ctx.Load($SiteColumn)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
    #Get the Site Column's Name,Type, ID and Group
    $SiteColumn | Select Title, TypeDisplayName, ID, Group
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error: " $_.Exception.Message
}
```

**Source**: [SharePoint Online: PowerShell to Get Site Columns](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/07/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-get-site-columns.html)

Comment: thanks for the script, but will it work if the service account have MFA enabled ?

Comment: It should work. If normal password is not working, use App password instead of normal password. Check this for more information: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302388/connect-sposervice-the-sign-in-name-or-password-does-not-match-one-in-the-micr/302391#302391

Comment: @Genesh Sanap seems i can use `ClientContext ctx = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext("SiteUrl", "AppId", "AppSecret");  ` but ACSAppOnly is disabled in our tenant.. any advice?